# Ошибка импорта пакета - attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, linux, импорт

**Проблема**: при попытке запуска файла `train.py`, содержащего такие строки импорта (снизу), возникает ошибка `attempted relative import with no known parent package`. Помогите, **пожалуйста**, решить эту проблему. Пробовал абсолютные/относительные способы импорта, добавлял `init.py` файлы куда только можно, но не работает ничего.

```
...
from .directory_3.subdirectory_3 import file_1
from .directory_3.subdirectory_3 import file_2
from .directory_3.subdirectory_3 import file_3
...
```

**Структура файлов**:

```
/root:
    /directory_1
    /directory_2
    /directory_3
        /subdirectory_1
        /subdirectory_2
        /subdirectory_3      *here*
            /file_1.py
            /file_2.py
            /file_3.py
        /train.py      *here*
        /...
    /...
```

**Примечание**: я использую Google Colab Notebook

Comment: А пробовали from root.directory_3.subdirectory_3 import file_1?

Comment: @СергейКох, данный вариант тоже не работает. НО я исправил эту ошибку, используя абсолютный импорт "import subdirectory_3.file_1"